# How to Launch and Debug WSL C++ Binary from Within Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-subsystem-for-linux, visual-studio-debugging

I want to be able to launch and debug a WSL Linux binary from within Visual Studio.

**EDIT**:

Please note that I want to build within WSL, i.e. `gcc -g test.cpp -o test` and only use Visual Studio to launch and debug the binary. Ideally I would like something like: `devenv.exe /debugexe <binary>` for a Linux binary. This would probably equate to something like `DebugAdapterHost.Launch /LaunchJson:c:\wsl\vs\launch.json` inside the command-window.

Taking the approach from [this article](https://medium.com/criteo-labs/wsl-visual-studio-attaching-launching-a-linux-net-core-application-on-my-window-10-ab21c179702d), the following is a `launch.json` that acheives this for .NET:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "adapter": "c:\\tools\\plink.exe",
  "adapterArgs": "-ssh -pw <password> chrisnas@DBGDQPZ1 -batch -T ~/vsdbg/vsdbg --interpreter=vscode",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": ".NET Core Launch",
      "type": "coreclr",
      "cwd": "/mnt/d/wsl/TestConsole/TestConsole/bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.1/publish",
      "program": "TestConsole.dll",
      "request": "launch"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have seen articles that use GDBServer, however this a lot more cumbersome than the approach outlined above.

How could this be modified to work with C++?

Comment: I would recommend looking into the premade configurations that Visual Studio offers, and go on from there. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/c-with-visual-studio-2019-and-windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl/) for instructions on how to set it up.

Comment: @Rane I'm building within WSL. I only want to use Visual Studio's debugger. That blog post is for building in Visual Studio targeting WSL.

Comment: There are separate build and debug/launch configuration files in VSC. If you don't want to build, don't use the build configuration. The debug/launch configuration is independent and unrelated.

Comment: @Ryan McClue What do you mean by "building within wsl?" I thought that wsl was just a runtime/ base layer for running linux apps in windows, like MinGW.